# What automorphisms exist on the abelian group of positive rationals under multiplication?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, rational-numbers, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Consider the abelian group $(\mathbb{Q}_{>0}, \times)$.
What automorphisms exist for this group?
I can only think of the trivial one and of $\phi(q) = \frac{1}{q}$.

If we relax the problem to injective homomophisms from $(\mathbb{Q}_{>0}, \times)$ to itself, do we get additional results?

Comment: It is the direct product of its subgroups $\{p^k \mid k \in {\mathbb Z} \}$ for primes $p$, so you can define $2^{\aleph_0}$ automorphism by inverting the elements of any subset of these direct factors.

Comment: What about a generic permutation of the prime numbers?

Comment: Can it easily be shown that these are the only ones?

Comment: No, because they are not!

Comment: Is there a reasonable way to find all of them?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $(\Bbb Q_{> 0}, \cdot)$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z, +) \oplus (\Bbb Z, +) \oplus \cdots$.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to first talk about endomorphisms because these have a ring structure. In fact, as has been mentioned a few times already, this group is a countable direct sum $\bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}$ of a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ for every prime, and hence in some respects it behaves like a vector space. In particular, its endomorphism ring $\text{End}(\bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z})$ is a ring of matrices: more precisely, it's the ring of integer matrices with countably many rows and columns, but where there are a finite number of entries in each column (*column-finite matrices* for short). This condition ensures that multiplying such a matrix by a "vector" in $\bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}$ is well-defined.

The automorphism group is then the group of units of this ring: that is, it's the group of invertible column-finite matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$. I think that is as simple of a description as you're going to get. This is a very large group; it includes the groups $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ for all $n$ as proper subgroups, as well as the group $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{N})$ of all permutations of a countable set.